# How to connect Snowflake with Superset by sqlalchemy connection string with Azure AD SSO

Tags: sqlalchemy, azure-active-directory, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, connection-string, apache-superset

I tried to use sqlalchemy connection string to establish connection between snowflake and superset, but due to my snowflake has Azure AD SSO integrated, how can I use sqlalchemy connection string to successfully complete my connection?

BTW, I have noticed [authenticator = 'externalbrowser'] could help, but when executing connection string with [authenticator = 'externalbrowser'] inside superset, superset can not open external browser for me to complete authentication, does anyone know other way to do SSO in connection string?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to set up Azure External Oauth for Snowflake and then use it for the connection between the intended application and SF. Once the OAuth setup is completed, then pass the following 2 parameters as follows for connecting with the oauth token:

```
authenticator = 'oauth'
token='<token value generated>'
```

For instance, connecting Databricks to Snowflake using OAuth as detailed here: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-To-Connect-To-Snowflake-From-Azure-Databricks-Using-OAuth-Client-Credentials